# java generics error: capture ? extends MyClass

Tags: java, generics

I'm sure this must have been asked before but I don't know the right terminology to search for it. Please point me to the duplicate if you find it.

This is another generics question.

Suppose I'm working with this method (which I cannot change the signature of)

```
class Shelter {
    public <T> JsonNode feedAnimal(Class<T> pojoType, T pojo) { ... }
}
```

And I want to pass in a pojo that I don't know the type of ahead of time

```
class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

Animal animal = new Cat();
```

How do I feed the cat?

I could do this

```
shelter.feedAnimal(Cat.class, (Cat) animal);
```

But it might be a dog or some other animal.

I tried doing this

```
shelter.<Animal>feedAnimal(animal.getClass(), animal);
```

But I get an error that says

> Required Class <Animal>.
>
> Provided Class <capture of ? extends Animal>

What sort of generics magic can I use to make this work?

**Edit**
@ElliottFrisch answer in the comment is correct. I can simply do

```
shelter.feedAnimal(Animal.class, animal);
```

`feedAnimal` is actually a serialization method. I was afraid that by specifying the parent class, it wouldn't serialize the subclass fields. That turned out to be an incorrect assumption.

There's a corresponding deserialization method. This is where I needed to specify the subclass being deserialized. This part is not a problem

Comment: `shelter.feedAnimal(Animal.class, animal);`

Comment: The method converts the pojo to a `JsonNode`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't know if this matters, but this feedAnimal method is actually serializing the pojo to a `JsonNode`. I'm afraid your approach will only serialize the fields in Animal but not Cat or Dog

Comment: Why is the method generic? Why not just call `getClass` on `pojo` within the method?

Comment: Exactly as tgdavies has said - such a method shouldn't need to be generic. Where is this method from? Can you see how it is implemented?

Comment: "I'm afraid your approach will only serialize the fields in Animal but not Cat or Dog" So it's getting the fields to serialise from the `pojoType`, instead of the `pojo` parameter? I have *never* seen such a design before...

Comment: If what I assumed above was true, then `shelter.feedAnimal((Class<Animal>)animal.getClass(), animal);` should be safe.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you want this, but you could also do `public <T> JsonNode feedAnimal(Class<? extends T> pojoType, T pojo) { ... }`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch is right. My concerns with the serializer not recognizing all the fields of the subclass were unfounded. It was in the deserialization where I need to provide the subclass